# Use regex to split elements in a list comprehension after a character

Tags: python, regex

I would like to split a list taking characters after the split point into another list

I think the answer is along the lines of

```
[re.sub(r'......', '', i) for i in x]
```

Here is the list I want to split

```
['260=2.31', '264=0.68', '265=0.25', '266=3.56', '267=0.05', '268=6.71']
```

putting all before the "=" into one list

```
['260','264','265','266','267','268']
```

and all after the "=" into another list

```
['2.31','0.68','0.25','3.56','0.05','6.71']
```

thanks!

Comment: split each element by `=` and place the first and second element from splitted list as per your requirement in `list1` and `list2`

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> l = ['260=2.31', '264=0.68', '265=0.25', '266=3.56', '267=0.05', '268=6.71']
>>> l1, l2 = zip(*[item.split("=") for item in l])
>>> l1
('260', '264', '265', '266', '267', '268')
>>> l2
('2.31', '0.68', '0.25', '3.56', '0.05', '6.71')
```

Comment: It's good to mention that this will give you two tuples instead of lists. To convert them to lists, just use `l1 = list(l1)`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
myList = ['260=2.31', '264=0.68', '265=0.25', '266=3.56', '267=0.05', '268=6.71']
listA = list(
    map(
        lambda x: x.split("=")[0],
        myList
    )
)
listB = list(
    map(
         lambda x: x.split("=")[1],
         myList
    )
)
```

Edit:
Tim Pietzcker's approach is much better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use regex you can do:

```
import re
l = ['260=2.31', '264=0.68', '265=0.25', '266=3.56', '267=0.05', '268=6.71']
matches = [re.match(r'([.\d]*)=([.\d]*)', x) for x in l]
l1 = [m.group(1) for m in matches]
l2 = [m.group(2) for m in matches]

print(l1)
print(l2)
```

Which produces;

```
['260', '264', '265', '266', '267', '268']  
['2.31', '0.68', '0.25', '3.56', '0.05', '6.71']
```